# Issue with FOR loop repeating

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

The task is to find out if a number is prime. I did some research and came up with the following code:

```
    using System;

class PrimeOrNot
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write a natural number:");
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (number == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not prime"); //is 1 prime?
        }
        if (number == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is Prime");
        }

        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not prime");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 3; i < number; i += 2)
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not Prime");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Is Prime");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that if the number passes the tests all the way to that FOR function, it gets funky. It prints lots of "Is Prime" if it's prime and if it isn't, it prints lots of "Is Prime" and a few of "Not Prime. I debugged it step by step and saw where the problem stems from, but I can't figure out a solution.

So how do I deal with this?

EDIT:

SO I shrinked the IFs in the beginning the way Frank suggested, then used BradleyDotNET's code and voila. Today I learned about breaking loops. The code I ended up is this:

```
using System;

class PrimeOrNot
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write a natural number:");
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        bool isPrime = true;
        if (number > 1 && number % 2 != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 3; isPrime && i < number; i += 2)
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isPrime = false;
        }

        if (isPrime)
            Console.WriteLine("Number is prime!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Number is not prime.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pedantically speaking, if, else and for are not operators. :)

Comment: Every loop iteration you printing one of two messages.  Perhaps you meant to store the results into some sort of bool variable.  Then check later the result and print either "Prime" or "not"

Comment: check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @Almo I knew it! Sorry for that, I'm pretty new and forgot the term.

Comment: Not a big deal. I recognize it doesn't change the content of your question. :)

Comment: Hint: it would make life easier if you extracted the operation of "determine whether or not a number is prime" into a separate method. Then you can return as soon as you know the answer - and where you're currently printing "Is Prime" you *don't* know the answer...

Comment: Another short cut is to only increment up to the square root of the number as any factors bigger than the square root will have a matching factor less than the square root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off that code doesn't really check if the number is prime.

When you get into the for loop you have this condition:

```
if (number % i == 0)
```

Which is checked for every number between 3 and your number, incrementing by two. That uses modulus (which returns the remainder of number divided by i). So basically, for every number in that set that evenly divides the input, you get a "Not Prime" output and for every other number a "Prime" output.

If you want just *one* output, set a boolean variable during your loop, then check it outside the loop to to do the output. Here's a sample:

```
bool isPrime = true;

//Stopping the loop once we know its not prime is better
//Note that it won't even evaluate i < number if isPrime fails
for (int i = 3; isPrime && i < number; i += 2)
{
   if (number % i == 0)
   {
       isPrime = false;

       //Adding this line makes us more efficient
       //Some people don't like breaking flow like this though
       break; //We're done
   }
}

if (isPrime)
   Console.WriteLine("Number is prime!");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Number is not prime.");
```

Note that the code includes two ways to make it more efficient. Don't actually use both in the real code, since they have the same effect :)

As Jon Skeet mentions in the comments, you could refactor the first block into a method, which is a very good way to increase the readability and reuse of the code.

Comment: I would add a break statement in the for loop, or more "advanced" add it to the for loop check. Being efficient should be taught from Day 1 IMO.

Comment: for (int i = 3; isPrime && i < number; i += 2)

Comment: @Al-Muhandis Added both methods into my sample, as efficiency *is* important.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET you might even just code 'isPrime = number % i != 0;' and get rid of the if ... thats if you use the the additional condition in the for header

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger yes, but then you are doing assignment in a conditional, which is almost always *terrible* practice. Certainly not something to get in the habit of.

Comment: No I meant get rid of the if too... just leave 'isPrime = number % i != 0;' as the body of the for loop

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger I know that, and that's still a conditional expression (the second argument of a for loop *has* to be a conditional expression). It's still bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the number 1 is excluded from being a prime. I have no idea why because technically it can only be divided by 1 and by itself. Meh. 1 is not a prime number.

The number 2 is absolutely a prime as the number 2 can only be divided by 1 and by itself.

So I might change your first three if{} to read if(n > 1 && n % 2 != 0). That should get you through to the number 3 (I think).

Then let your for{} loop kick in at the else{}. Unfortunatel the i is not testing your int number. It's testing all the numbers between the number your inputing and 3.

Just another if statement would do the trick. No need to loop through all the numbers your testing. I think the if statement I wrote first might do it?? Hmm....

***EDIT: Respectfully, I can't add comments, the OP is asking to test his `number` for prime or not prime, not all numbers between 3 and his input.***

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be the fact that your code is supplying a recommendation for every iteration of the loop from 3 to your number. Instead, you might want it to just do an evaluation for every odd value and then just break if it finds an exception to the rule like this:

```
using System;

namespace IsItPrime
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool exit = false;
            while (!exit) {

                Console.WriteLine("Write a natural number:");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (answer.Equals("x")) { 
                    exit = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    int number = int.Parse(answer);

                    if (number == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not prime"); //is 1 prime?
                    }
                    else if (number == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not Prime");
                    }
                    else if (number % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not prime");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bool isPrime = false;
                        for (int i = 3; i < number; i += 2)
                        {
                            if (number % i == 0)
                            {
                                isPrime = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (isPrime)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Not Prime");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Is Prime");
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```